# String variable as name of object?

Tags: java, variables, loops, object, naming

writing a program which reads a file, and saves the information into an array of objects.

I am currently working on a loop to read the file and break it into chunks for each object, but I’m stuck on how to set the variable `accountname` as the name of the object … any advice?

```
while (objects > 0) {
  objects = objects - 1;
  objectNumber = objectNumber + 1;
  Name = scanner.nextLine();
  accountnumber = scanner.nextLine();
  balance = scanner.nextLine();

  System.out.println(Name + " " + accountnumber + " " + balance + "\n");

  String accountname = "a" + objectNumber;

  Account ___________ = new Account(Name, accountnumber, balance);
}
```

Comment: You'll be stuck forever since this can't be done. Maybe you want to store these objects in array?

Comment: If there is one thing I have learned from CS, nothing CANT be done

Comment: A better question would be: why would you want to do this?

Comment: @user2954611 Can you write a program that converts elephants to rabbits? :D

Comment: The point of the program is to read a file input regarding bank account info (names, account number, balance) seperate the file into seperate account objects and then be able to refer to each of the objects seperately

Comment: But you don't have to name a variable to something specifically for that for that purpose. It looks like what you need is a Map.

Comment: how would one use a map?

Comment: It's also pointless because the names would be generated dynamically from the input at runtime, so at design time, you would have no way to refer to any of the objects again. You need to store them in some kind of collection/list/array.

Answer (score 0):

*"The point of the program is to read a file input regarding bank account info (names, account number, balance) seperate the file into seperate account objects and then be able to refer to each of the objects seperately"*

It looks like what you really need is a map

```
Map<String, Account> accountsByName = new HashMap<String, Account>();
accountsByName.put(accountName, account);
Account yourAccount = accountsByName.get(accountname);
```

Comment: I have never used maps before, how does something like this fit into my pre-existing code?

Comment: a Map stores key, value pairs... the key being the account name, the value being the Account object... (with all its properties populated by your program)